# Delete Previous Open Id Account From StackOverflow

Tags: support, stack-overflow, openid

I want to remove my old openid from StackOverflow because I want to use my email id associated with the previous account in my new account.

As I have forgotten my open id provider and I don't see anyway to figure out what was the open id provider I used for my previous account.

**My email id is :** -removed sensitive data-  (Used in Previous Account)
**Previous Account:** https://stackoverflow.com/users/25138/zuhaib
**New Account :** https://stackoverflow.com/users/26440/zuhaibz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just email team@stackoverflow.com - they're the ones who will be able to deal with this.

Comment: We (♦) can also deal with this, btw.